# RegEx: Check if italics closing tag exists in first line

Tags: regex

I just can't get this to work.
Scenario: Subtitling, SRT format. If  the first out of two lines contains an opening italics tag `<i>` and the italicized part of the text extends into the second line, then the first line needs a closing tag `</i>` at its end and the second line an opening tag `<i>` at its beginning.

Approach: If `<i>` is found in line1, then look if there is a closing tag in that line. If yes, do nothing, if not, then replace line1 minus its line break with: `line1</i>\n<i>`.

This is what I've tried:

Find: `(.*<i>.*(?!.*</i>.*\n))\n`
Replace with: `$1<i/>\n<i>`

Problem: Although there is an instance of a closing tag after an opening tag in line1, this gives out a match.

Line1 and line2 refer to the text lines in the blocks below, so ignore the lines with the numbers and the time code.

Example material:

```
1
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:03,320
<i>Alle meine Entchen
schwimmen auf dem See</i>

2
00:00:04,240 --> 00:00:06,880
<i>Köpfchen</i> in das Wasser
Schwänzchen in die <i>Höh</i>.

3
00:00:06,960 --> 00:00:08,960
<i>(Musik endet ♪,</i>
<i>Männerstimme, Englisch:)</i>
```

1: should get a closing tag at the end of line1 and an opening tag at the start of line2

2 and 3: Should not be considered a match and be left alone

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Best,

Ingo

Comment: Are you working in Notepad++?

Comment: Your approach is broken: It doesn't correct `<i>foo</i> bar <i>baz`.

Comment: I could work in Notepad++, but this is the Multiple Replace Regex engine in Subtitle Edit that I am using. I can feed this material anywhere, though, if there's place where it can be done.

Comment: Does the tool work in multiline mode, can it match several lines with one regex? Is there any online documentation?

Comment: Of course, it should continue down the whole first line even after it's found a closing tag if there is another opening tag with a missing closing tag.

Comment: I think it works in multiline mode, but I'd have to ask the developer to be sure as there is no documentation available. But just assume it does for now.

Comment: https://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/help there are some screenshots and basic information on  this tool. Search inside the page for Multiple Replace.

Comment: So, it supports .NET regex engine.

Comment: In your third subtitle, you should have `<i>(Musik endet ♪,</i>`, not `<i>(Musik endet ♪,<i/>`, right?

Comment: Try 1) `(?m)(?<=^<i>(?!.*</i>).*)$` => `</i>` and 2) `(?m)^(?=.*(?<!<i>.*)</i>\r?$)` => `<i>`

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor. 1) doesn't work properly, 2) is close, only it doesn't put the end tag in line 1.

Comment: No idea what that feedback means. What do you mean by "doesn'twork properly"? They must be used one by one.

Comment: Sorry. 1) puts a line break before the end tag, so there are two line breaks afterwards.

Comment: See [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%3ci%3e%28%3f!.*%3c%2fi%3e%29.*%29%24&i=%0d%0a%3ci%3eAlle+meine+Entchen%0d%0aschwimmen+auf+dem+See%3c%2fi%3e&r=%3c%2fi%3e&o=m) and [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%5e%28%3f%3d.*%28%3f%3c!%3ci%3e.*%29%3c%2fi%3e%5cr%3f%24%29&i=%0d%0a%3ci%3eAlle+meine+Entchen%3c%2fi%3e%0d%0aschwimmen+auf+dem+See%3c%2fi%3e&r=%3ci%3e&o=m). See *Context* tab.

Comment: It looks all right there, but this... (?m)(?<=^<i>(?!.*</i>).*)$ =></i> puts a line break before the ending tag. <i>xxx<br />yyy  becomes <i>xxx<br /></i><br />yyy

Answer (score 0):

You were close, with the negative lookahead.  Here's how you might identify a line with an opening `<i>` that's not followed by its corresponding closing `</i>` using JS:

```js
// this should not modify the string, as it
// contains the closing </i> element
console.log(
  "this <i>is a</i> test".replace(/(?!<i>.+<\/i>)(<i>.+$)/g, '$1</i>')
);

// this one should modify the string, appending
// the closing </i> to the end
console.log(
  "this <i>is a test".replace(/(?!<i>.+<\/i>)(<i>.+$)/g, '$1</i>')
);
```

And, here's a demonstration, in Python, as requested:

```
>>> import re;

>>> print(re.sub(r'(?!<i>.+<\/i>)(<i>.+$)', r'\1</i>', "this <i>is a</i> test"))
this <i>is a</i> test

>>> print(re.sub(r'(?!<i>.+<\/i>)(<i>.+$)', r'\1</i>', "this <i>is a test"))
this <i>is a test</i>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I tried it at https://regex101.com and I couldn't get it to work. Can anyone translate this into Perl or Python?

Comment: @DigitalLowlife I've added a demonstration in Python, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your fantastic input. It helped me to construct the following solution, which also works for the case of a second instance of an opening tag, like this

```
<i>Köpfchen</i> in <i>das Wasser
Schwänzchen in die Höh</i>.
```

=>

```
<i>Köpfchen</i> in <i>das Wasser</i>
<i>Schwänzchen in die Höh</i>.
```

and it doesn't introduce any new line breaks.

step1

```
(?m)(?<=<i>(?!.*</i>).*$?)\r   => </i>
```

step2

```
(?m)^(?=.*(?<!<i>.*)</i>.*\r?$) => <i>
```